# Term Document Frequencies in Java with Lucene/Lingpipe in a large corpus

Tags: java, lucene, text-analysis

I am trying to analyze a large corpus of documents, which are in a huge file (3.5GB, 300K lines, 300K documents), one document per line. In this process I am using Lucene for indexing and Lingpipe for preprocessing.

The problem is that I want to get rid of very rare words in the documents. For example, if a word occurs less than MinDF times in the corpus (the huge file), I want to remove it.

I can try to do it with Lucene: Compute the Document Frequencies for all distinct terms, sort them in ascending order, get the terms that have DF lower than MinDF, go over the huge file again, and remove these terms line per line.

This process will be insanely slow. Does anybody know of any quicker way to do this using Java?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a temp index, then use the information in it to produce the final index. Use `IndexReader.terms()`, iterate over that, and you have `TermEnum.docFreq` for each term. Accumulate all low-freq terms and then feed that info into an analyzer that extends `StopWordAnalyzerBase` when you are creating the final index.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful answer, I'll report back!